# How is battery charge reported to the operating system?

Tags: laptop, battery, kernel, battery-life

This feels like a [stack exchange EE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) question, but it seems like it belongs here instead.

How is the charge of a notebook computer's battery reported to the operating system? Since all laptop batteries I've seen seem to be cross-platform, there must be some standard procedure to inform the kernel of the charge level.

The best I can think of is that some microcontroller has to maintain a serial connection and inform the OS of the battery's voltage, but I can't figure out how this applies to determining things like whether the AC is plugged in or how this information is reported to the OS.

This seems like such a basic problem, but Googling it just led me to consumers trying to increase their battery life.

Comment: Here's a page with good info: [How laptop batteries work](http://www.instructables.com/id/Increase-the-capacity-runtime-of-your-laptop-bat/step2/How-laptop-batteries-work/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The specification you are referring to is the [Smart Battery Specification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_Battery_System), which reports the data to the [System Management Bus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Management_Bus). The SMBus is responsible for a whole host of things in addition to battery information such as temperatures, fan speed, etc.

There was a [BlackHat presentation](http://media.blackhat.com/bh-us-11/Miller/BH_US_11_Miller_Battery_Firmware_Public_WP.pdf) (link is PDF) that goes into the real details of how this system reports data, and how you can hack it for fun.